# red5 decode error on Linux

Tags: red5

I am building a 2-way video chat app with Red5. When I run the app in my Windows environment, it works fine, but when I try to use it on Linux, I get an error that the live stream cannot be decoded. HEre is the error:

```
2012-02-18 01:32:20,955 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Stream start
2012-02-18 01:32:20,959 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.a.MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter - W3C x-category:stream x-event:publish c-ip:223.205.177.236 x-sname:aaeec362-7a79-41d2-b572-1c2962fa1a77 x-name:doctorb
2012-02-18 01:32:21,591 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.server.stream.VideoCodecFactory - Trying codec org.red5.server.stream.codec.ScreenVideo@565539d8
2012-02-18 01:32:21,591 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.server.stream.VideoCodecFactory - Trying codec org.red5.server.stream.codec.SorensonVideo@7548c02f
2012-02-18 01:32:21,592 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 5246 to 5305
2012-02-18 01:32:21,629 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 5339 to 5369
2012-02-18 01:32:21,896 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 5625 to 5689
2012-02-18 01:32:22,547 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 6439 to 6491
2012-02-18 01:32:22,847 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 6848 to 6907
2012-02-18 01:32:23,597 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 7594 to 7643
2012-02-18 01:32:26,249 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 10272 to 10331
2012-02-18 01:32:27,450 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 11366 to 11387
2012-02-18 01:32:28,150 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 12059 to 12091
2012-02-18 01:32:29,250 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 13149 to 13179
2012-02-18 01:32:29,501 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 13523 to 13563
2012-02-18 01:32:30,479 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 14320 to 14363
2012-02-18 01:32:30,646 [NioProcessor-2] WARN  org.red5.server.Context - Bean lookup failed for everyone_37b0bf5186e9a223d514a0641f4cbef0..soservice in the application context
2012-02-18 01:32:30,688 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 14725 to 14779
2012-02-18 01:32:31,251 [NioProcessor-1] WARN  org.red5.server.Context - Bean lookup failed for everyone_37b0bf5186e9a223d514a0641f4cbef0..soservice in the application context
2012-02-18 01:32:31,634 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 15518 to 15547
2012-02-18 01:32:32,703 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 16605 to 16635
2012-02-18 01:32:33,703 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 17699 to 17755
2012-02-18 01:32:33,994 [NioProcessor-1] WARN  org.red5.server.Context - Bean lookup failed for everyone_37b0bf5186e9a223d514a0641f4cbef0..soservice in the application context
2012-02-18 01:32:34,904 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - dispatchEvent: adjust archaic videoTime, from: 18755 to 18811
2012-02-18 01:32:35,500 [NioProcessor-2] ERROR o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Error decoding buffer
org.red5.server.net.protocol.ProtocolException: Error during decoding
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decode(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:196) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodeBuffer(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:119) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPMinaProtocolDecoder.decode(RTMPMinaProtocolDecoder.java:61) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:225) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:433) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:801) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:119) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:433) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:425) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:603) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:563) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:552) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:56) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:891) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) [mina-core-2.0.0-M6.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [na:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at org.red5.io.amf3.Input.readString(Input.java:349) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.object.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodeNotifyOrInvoke(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:828) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodeInvoke(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:734) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodeMessage(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:506) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decodePacket(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:391) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder.decode(RTMPProtocolDecoder.java:182) [red5.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
2012-02-18 01:32:35,508 [NioProcessor-2] WARN  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Closing connection because decoding failed: RTMPMinaConnection from 223.205.177.236 : 5673 to 184.107.183.106 (in: 3906 out 4006 )
```

Comment: This down voting system is bullshit. Someone can just downvote without any explanation why? How does that help anything? If you think there is something about it that does not 'show research effort' or is 'unclear', then say something. I spent hours looking around the internet and posting here is a last resort deal.

Comment: its true that the vote system has flaws just as we do, but it also doesn't help anyone when others here have agendas and down-vote "competing" projects / devs.

Answer (score 0):

Lee, try the newer builds of Red5 like revision 4329 or newer; from your log it would seem that you're using 0.7 or older.
http://red5.googlecode.com/